# Read a text file by delimiter not by line break

Tags: programming, delimiters, filesystem-access

I would like to populate a table, which I created in my LaTeX document, using iterating over cells of a text file.

In order to read the text file I use this code.

```
\newread\data
\openin\data = data
\loop\unless\ifeof\data
\read\data to\cell
% do stuff with \cell
\repeat
\closein\file
```

As you know, `\read` reads until it encounters a line break. Nevertheless, I would not like this behavior and I am more interested in reading cell by cell. In particular, reading by a certain delimiter. For example, `tab`, `;`, or whatever else.

**TL;DR:** Is there a command similar to `\read` to keep reading until it reaches to a certain delimiter?

**Note:** I already know there is a CSV package out there which just do what I am trying to do. However, in this case I would rather prefer reinventing the wheel!

---

**UPDATE #1:**

Example of the text file:

```
1   2   3   4
A   B   C   D
```

Comment: An example of the file to be read in?

Comment: It depends. You either read line by line (to something, and then parse each line for `;` or whatever) or use `\input` rather than `\read` in which case you can just parse in the normal way.

Comment: @egreg Example has been added. `tab` is the delimiter.

Comment: @abforce TeX will read line by line anyway. You can split the line after it has been read and do a loop on the items.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm new in LaTeX. Could you please explain how can I parse each line?

Comment: tex parsing usually comes down to using _delimited macro arguments_ (there are several answers on site about that) here delimited by space (newlines and tabs will be reported as a space token by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1 {\def\zza{#1}%
\ifx\zza\zzb\else
\stepcounter{enumi}%
Field \theenumi\ is \fbox{\zza}\par
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zz
\fi}
\def\zzb{\relax?}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\zz\@@input testdata.txt\relax?


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much sir. It seems your codes are very different with mine. I couldn't understand, though. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: @abforce you asked for low level code, not a packaged interface, so this is probably as simple/short as it can be. As I say there are several answers describing delimited macro arguments.

Comment: Excuse me sir. Isn't there a way to just split my `\cell` variable in a in-line way?

Comment: (don't call me sir:-) the above code spits up its input on spaces you could use exactly the same command applied to the expansion of `\cell` to split up each line separately, although that isn't really necessary if you are splitting the whole file, as you see.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your time and consideration.